# CSS compilation with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just started working on angular 4.0.0 and angular-cli is nice to have.
But i am facing issue with compiling sass files.

rather than parsing all components .scss file as one , webpack is adding a inline style tag with all the css inside it .

Is it an expected behavior or i am missing some configuration for node-sass and sass-loader in angular-cli

```
     "styles": [
    "styles.scss"
  ],
   "defaults": {
"styleExt": "scss",
"component": {}
```

}

thats the cli configuration for styles.

for the app configuration styles.scss import app.components.scss and
app.component.scss imports all other component's scss.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's not webpack doing the inline styles but Angular. It's how it works so **expected behavior** Read up on [ViewEncapsulation](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if one component is overriding property of other component . And Each components styles are included in HEAD in separate styles  will it create conflict ? cause i am facing this issue where static html page with css works in all browsers but when i divided it into two components its breaking in IE

Comment: Like I said, "read" about ViewEncapsulation. You clearly don't understand it yet, nor what is really happening with those injected style tags

Answer (score 0):

The file `styles.scss` is typically used to store global styles. Please read more about it over here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles

If you are having issues styling issues - please double check to ensure you have node-sass included in your package.json. If not, then `npm install node-sass --save-dev`

If I'm understanding your question right then yes it is expected behavior and Angular calls that behavior *View Encapsulation*. You can read more about it and how Angular works with styles here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html